# Headers for HttpRequest, Angular with Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

using Angular with an API built in Spring Boot.
I have a problem regarding sending a request with the headers with the associated JWT.
The problems seems to be that i don't send any headers at all to my API.

> Angular:

```
greetingFunc() {

    const headers_auth = {
        'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem("token")!
    }

    this.httpClient.get<string>(
        "http://localhost:8080/greeting", {
        'headers': headers_auth
    }).subscribe(
        data => {
            const greet = data;
            return greet; 
        }
    )
}
```

When inspecting page in my browser, I get the Error saying that my headers are empty:
headers: HttpHeaders
headers: Map(0)
[[Entries]]
No properties
size: 0
[[Prototype]]: Map

> API (Spring Boot)

> System.out.println(requestTokenHeader);
> -->Prints null

> System.out.println(request.getHeader("Authorization"));
> -->Prints null

[image: When running in postman i have the following headers]
I have been trying the code in PostMan, where it works fine.

[image: httpHeaders]

[image: httpOptions]

[image: Code that has been tested]

[image: intercept that is provided in app.module.ts with providers]

Comment: you can use [interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

Comment: I should not need to do that, do you know how to solve it without using intercept?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have new instance of HttpHeaders

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    Authorization: 'my-auth-token'
  })
};
```

and then

```
this.httpClient.get<"http://localhost:8080/greeting", httpOptions)
```

Comment: Sorry, that does not do it. 


`const httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type':  'application/json',Authorization: sessionStorage.getItem("token")!})};`



`this.httpClient.get<string>("http://localhost:8080/greeting", httpOptions).subscribe(
            data=>{console.log(data); }
        );
`


Results in: headers: Map(0)

Comment: Does not work, would highly appreciate your help. 
Thank you

Comment: Hey @Filip_k_island,

If you do console.log(httpOptions) what are you getting ?

Comment: So, I get the following: {headers: HttpHeaders}, -> lazyint, normalizedNames: Map(0) {size:0}

Comment: I have updated my question and added pictures for describing my httpHeaders, httpOptions and my get method

Comment: As i can see the headers are fine, and the console is printing out what its supposed to.
Do you get Status Code 200 OK on GET /greetings ?

Comment: Solved it, had wrong configurations in my Spring Boot. Funny, cause the API worked when I used Postman. 

Thank you for ur help!

Comment: Nice to hear @Filip_k_island :) I thought that might be a possibility

Comment: @Filip_k_island can you share plz how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

!SOLVED
In Spring Boot when overriding the addCorsMapping just add *.exposedHeaders(header_name)* in the registry chain.

Example:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedOrigins(clientPort)
        .allowedMethods(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.PATCH.name(), HttpMethod.DELETE.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name())
        .allowedHeaders(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
        .exposedHeaders(JwtHeader)
        .allowCredentials(true)
        .maxAge(86400);
}
```